# Embed Powerpoint slides in Word document

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to embed a powerpoint slide in a word document.

I **don't** want to export it as JPG and insert the picture into my word document. I want it to be "dynamically linked", i.e. whenever I edit/change/update my slide the word document gets changed too.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

I am aware that this question is primarily about Office 2007. This option is available in 2010, and may be missing in 2007.

---

### Paste special, as link

This is based on [harrymc's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/73592/embed-powerpoint-slides-in-word-document#comment75578_73598).

1. Copy the entire PowerPoint slide. Select the slide thumbnail on the left list and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
2. Click the arrow under `Paste` in Word; select `Paste Special...`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> does the same thing.

   [[image: Screenshot of paste special option]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJpzO.png)
3. Select the `Paste link` radio button and `Microsoft PowerPoint Slide Object`

   [[image: Screenshot of paste special box]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGGFQ.png)

---

### Direct link by slide number?

As you may have noticed in my screenshots from the paste special, the link is actually specified by `filename.pptx!slidenumber`. I've tried, but it seems it's not possible to specify the slide number in this way when adding as an object. When adding an object, the only way to get a *Slide* rather than a *Presentation* is to create a new one, not add from file.

Basically, just use the paste special method.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Insert` ribbon then select the `Object` drop down (towards the right hand end).

On the dialog that comes up, select the `Create from File` tab, enter the name your Power Point and check the `Link to file` option.

**NOTE** This only links to the entire presentation rather than any one specific slide.

Comment: thanks. I just want to embed one slide as if I had exported it as JPG and inserted it into word.

Comment: @flybywire - I couldn't see any option to do that, sorry.

Comment: Best answer, but where did this feature go in word 2013??? Sigh.

Comment: Its still there, in the text 'box', not sure why I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

From the slide sorter view in PowerPoint, select the slide you want and copy it to the clipboard.  Then go to Word and paste it in the desired location.

Comment: Use Paste Special and paste as "Microsoft PowerPoint Slide Object".

Comment: This will paste the object rather than a link. The OP wants the Word doc to get updated when the Power Point updates.